# How to initialise an array in python in one line with if statement

Tags: python

How could I do the following in one line?

```
for j in range(len(cur)):
    if cur[j] == 1:
        partialres.append(normal[j])
```

I want something like

```py
 partialres = [normal[j] if cur[j] == 1 for j in range(len(cur)]
```

Comment: You are almost there, simply move the `if ...` statement to the end. For explanations: https://pythonguides.com/python-list-comprehension-using-if-else/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
partialres = [normal[j] for j in range(len(cur)) if cur[j] == 1 ]
```

Comment: thanks! that's exactly what I was looking for. Do you have some link to the documentation where exactly this gets explained? (how is this shorthand notation called?)

Comment: This is known as "List Comprehension"

Comment: The official documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the best to work with numpy ans masks:

```
import numpy as np

normal = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
cur = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,1,0])

mask = cur == 1
partialres = normal[mask]
print(mask)
print(partialres)
```

The definition of the `mask` is just for clarifictation.
If you want a one-liner:

```
partialres = normal[cur==1]
```

Comment: I know how it works for numpy, but I want to specifically know how it works for python lists

Comment: Okay then the answer of SeaBean is the correct way.